# Trying to get K-Means to do some basic clustering on text and ensure clusters are mutually exclusive

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

By it's nature K-Menas is mutually exclusive.  I found some code online that does clustering on text.  I'll admit, it's a little unorthodox, but kind of cool too.  Is there some way to get the sample code below to assign text to clusters and ensure that the text in each cluster is mutually exclusive?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["This little kitty came to play when I was eating at a restaurant.",
             "Merley has the best squooshy kitten belly.",
             "Google Translate app is incredible.",
             "If you open 100 tab in google you get a smiley face.",
             "Best cat photo I've ever taken.",
             "Climbing ninja cat.",
             "Impressed with google map feedback.",
             "Key promoter extension for Google Chrome."]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

true_k = 8
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=1000, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    print

print("\n")
print("Prediction")

Y = vectorizer.transform(["chrome browser to open."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)

Y = vectorizer.transform(["My cat is hungry."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)
```

Result:

```
Top terms per cluster:
Cluster 0:
 translate
 app
 incredible
 google
 eating
 impressed
 feedback
 face
 extension
 ve
Cluster 1:
 kitten
 belly
 squooshy
 merley
 best
 eating
 google
 feedback
 face
 extension
Cluster 2:
 eating
 kitty
 little
 came
 restaurant
 play
 ve
 feedback
 face
 extension
Cluster 3:
 ve
 taken
 photo
 best
 cat
 eating
 google
 feedback
 face
 extension
Cluster 4:
 impressed
 map
 feedback
 google
 ve
 eating
 face
 extension
 climbing
 key
Cluster 5:
 100
 open
 tab
 smiley
 face
 google
 feedback
 extension
 eating
 climbing
Cluster 6:
 chrome
 extension
 promoter
 key
 google
 eating
 impressed
 feedback
 face
 ve
Cluster 7:
 climbing
 ninja
 cat
 eating
 impressed
 google
 feedback
 face
 extension
 ve
```

I tried this:

```
documents = list(set(documents))
```

That still shows the same text items in more than one cluster.  I'm probably missing something simple here, but I have been working all morning (yes, on a Saturday) and getting tired now, so I'm just not seeing a solution here.

Comment: Same word appearing in different clusters maybe possibly due to the different contexts it appears in, in the data.

Comment: You are right!  I ended up using a dict to remove all duplicates and then fit the list to the vectorizer.  Thanks!

Solution: documents = list(dict.fromkeys(documents))